# Arrow font issue in Firefox

Tags: fonts

I'm not sure whether to file a bug report with Firefox or to get different fonts or what. The arrows in the normal (100% size) sans-serif font look lousy.

Could some of you try saving this as a file and viewing in Firefox? Any thoughts on what I should do to fix this?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
  div.box { border: 1px solid black; }
  .fsansserif { font-family: sans-serif; }
  .fserif { font-family: serif; }
  .sz110 { font-size: 110%; }
  .sz100 { font-size: 100%; }
  .sz090 { font-size: 90%; }
  .sz080 { font-size: 80%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  Why do a few of the arrows look lousy when all the rest look ok?
  (winXP, Firefox 3.5: the 100% sans-serif look 
  bad, so do the left arrows at 80%)
  <div class='box fsansserif'>Sans-serif:
    <p class='sz110'>110%: &larr; &harr; &rarr; </p>
    <p class='sz100'>100%: &larr; &harr; &rarr; </p>
    <p class='sz090'> 90%: &larr; &harr; &rarr; </p>
    <p class='sz080'> 80%: &larr; &harr; &rarr; </p>
  </div>
  <div class='box fserif'>Serif:
    <p class='sz110'>110%: &larr; &harr; &rarr; </p>
    <p class='sz100'>100%: &larr; &harr; &rarr; </p>
    <p class='sz090'> 90%: &larr; &harr; &rarr; </p>
    <p class='sz080'> 80%: &larr; &harr; &rarr; </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I see on my screen:

[image]

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: WinXP, Firefox 3.5 (I put this into the HTML code, should have stated up front I guess)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shot on Windows XP, Internet Explorer 7 side-by-side with Firefox 3.5.5. It doesn't look as bad on my system, but still looks less than ideal.

[image]

Comment: +1 for trying it... at least I know it's not just my system.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your text, and testing the arrows on my machine, I would say this is an operating system fault and related to clear type and general text rendering.... Also, a lot of fonts just look bad when zoomed in.

For a couple of bits of reference - [Jeff Atwood's My "Love/Hate relationship with ClearType"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000651.html) and also [ClearType (Unsung Hero of Windows)](http://www.agileprogrammer.com/dotnetguy/archive/2006/06/03/15617.aspx)

What Operating system are you using?

Comment: zoomed in?! it's at 100% scale... :/

Comment: (and if Firefox is asking for a scaled fontsize at 100% then it's a bug in Firefox)